# Sky-Form/Bootstrap 3: How to render multiple inputs that make it looks like 1 large input?

Tags: forms, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using sky-form library and bootstrap 3 to render my forms.

I have 3 inputs that I would like to wrap together.

I know that this requires custom css rules but I can't make it work as expected.

Please see attached image to better understand my need.

10x

[image]

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start. You may want to fiddle with the focus highlights a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/vqkma/

```
<style>
.joined-left {
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.joined-right {
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control joined-left" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control joined-right" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" />
</div>
```